# Change Images dynamically in lightbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have four links all with the same class like this

```
<a href="" class="learn-more">Learn More</a>
<a href="" class="learn-more">Learn More</a>
<a href="" class="learn-more">Learn More</a>
<a href="" class="learn-more">Learn More</a>
```

On clicking each of this link a lightbox will load. All the four links will load the same lightbox except the heading of the content in the lightbox. All the four lightboxes will have different heading, but the content are same. Also all the lightboxes will have the same product images except for the third link, which will have a different image. I need to achieve this in jQuery.

Comment: You need to make your links distinct. perhaps use href for the image location and add a name attribute or something for the header

Answer (score 2):

html:

```
    <a href="" class="learn-more" rel="0">Learn More</a>
    <a href="" class="learn-more" rel="1" >Learn More</a>
    <a href="" class="learn-more" rel="2" >Learn More</a>
    <a href="" class="learn-more" rel="3" >Learn More</a>
    <div class="LightBox">
    <div class="LightBox_h"><img src="image/img0.jpg">your text</div>
    <div calss="LightBox_b">your text</div>
    <div calss="LightBox_f">your text</div>
    </div><!--End LightBox-->
```

style:

```
LightBox{display:none}
```

query:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  $('.LightBox').css({'display':'block'}); 
  var i_see =  parseInt($(this).attr('rel'));        //  you can use  case 
  if ( i_see == 0){$('.LightBox_h').html('new next')}
     else if (i_see ==1){$('.LightBox_h').html('new next')}
        else if (i_see ==2){$('.LightBox_h').html('new next')}
            else if (i_see ==3){$('.LightBox_h').html('new next')}
});
```

some like this

or

```
var arr = ["img0" , "img1","img2" , "img3" ]; //sourse to img

   $('a').click(function(){
      $('.LightBox').css({'display':'block'}); 
      var i_see =  parseInt($(this).attr('rel'));       
      $('.LightBox_h img ').attr('src':'+ arr[i_see] +'); 

    });
```